# Swift iOS 8 upload image to WebServer

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I'm trying to post image of imageView as parameter called "image" and parameter "action" with value "upload" to web server through HTTP. 
How to do that in Swift iOS8?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at SRWeb library - https://github.com/sraj/Swift-SRWebClient

I am using below mentioned code and it works out fine :

```
var image_src = UIImage(named : "India")
var params = ["username":"uname", "password":"pwd"]
var img_data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image_src, 100)

SRWebClient.POST("http://a.b.c.d/servlet")
                 .data(img_data, fieldName: "param_name_for_img", data: params)
                 .send(
                       {(response:AnyObject!, status:Int) -> Void in
                       }
                  )
```